# Gets mismatched input '') as '' expecting

Tags: sql, apache-spark

My query in hadoop returns this error

```
mismatched input '') as '' expecting ,
```

I don't know why, anybody could find the issue?

```
select t1.* , '(sum(t1.'price') as 'price')'
from events t1
join
(
    SELECT min(idsite) as idsite
    FROM events
    GROUP BY idsite
) t2 on t1.idsite = t2.idsite
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about hadoop in particular, so maybe there's a dedicated syntax for this, but this looks fishy :

```
'(sum(t1.'price') as 'price')'
```

You have quotes pairs enclosed in another quotes pairs. The parser cannot understand this. It will assume the first one to be an opening one, the second one a closing one, the third one to reopen it again, and so on.